# Architecture Design using Queue and JWT Token for session management

Tags: architecture, web-development, microservices, session, jwt

I am planning to design a microservice system architecture for a ticketing platform. It will be similar to "TicketMaster". Here is the flow of my architecture:

1. client web browser
2. API gateway (nginx)
3. Virtual waiting room (AWS Simple Queue Service)
4. Once the user is out of the virtual waiting room (queue), an "identity" service will issue a JWT token, to allow users to access private routes, such as "ticket selection", "payment" and etc.
5. The JWT token will expire in 15 minutes.
6. The database will keep track of a list of "active" tokens and their expiry datetime
7. The "identity" service will periodically check the database "every minute" to clear any active tokens that have expired
8. This active token also serve as an indication to the number of online users within the private route.
9. If the system sets the maximum number of authorized users to be 1000, any additional users will be waiting at the virtual queue.
10. Once a user completes the payment or jwt token has expired, the counter will go down to allow the next person in the queue to enter.

Is the flow of my architecture good? I am just afraid of the number of queries to the database to check the list of active tokens. Is there any improvements?